# Vlookup from the same pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, vlookup

I have a hierarchical dataset that looks like this:

| emp_id | emp_name | emp_manager | emp_org_lvl |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John S | Bob A | 1 |
| 2 | Bob A | Paul P | 2 |
| 3 | Paul P | Charles Y | 3 |

What I want to do is extend this table to have the emp_name for each manager going up the org chart. E.g.

| emp_id | emp_name | emp_manager | emp_org_lvl | lvl2_name | lvl3_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John S | Bob A | 1 | Paul P | Charles Y |

In Excel, I would do a vlookup in column lvl2_name to see who Bob A's manager is e.g. something like this `vlookup(c2,B:C,2,False)`. Using pandas, the direction seems to be to use `Merge`. The problem with this is that `Merge` seems to require two separate dataframes and you can't specify what column to return. Is there a better way than having a separate dataframe for each emp_org_lvl?

```
#  Code to create table:

header = ['emp_id','emp_name','emp_manager','emp_org_lvl']
data = [[ 1,'John S'    ,'Bob A',   1],[2,  'Bob A',    'Paul P',   2],[3,  'Paul P',   'Charles Y',    3]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=header)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
# provide a lookup for employee to manager
manager_dict = dict(zip(df.emp_name, df.emp_manager))

# initialize the loop
levels_to_go_up = 3
employee_column_name = 'emp_manager'
# loop and keep adding columns to the dataframe
for i in range(2, levels_to_go_up + 1):
    new_col_name = f'lvl{i}_name'
    # create a new column by looking up employee_column_name's manager
    df[new_col_name] = df[employee_column_name].map(manager_dict)
    employee_column_name = new_col_name

>>>df
Out[67]: 
   emp_id emp_name emp_manager  emp_org_lvl  lvl2_name  lvl3_name
0       1   John S       Bob A            1     Paul P  Charles Y
1       2    Bob A      Paul P            2  Charles Y        NaN
2       3   Paul P   Charles Y            3        NaN        NaN
```

Alternatively if you wanted to retrieve ALL managers in the tree, you could use a recursive function, and return the results as a list:

```
def retrieve_managers(name, manager_dict, manager_list=None):
    if not manager_list:
        manager_list = []

    manager = manager_dict.get(name)
    if manager:
        manager_list.append(manager)
        return retrieve_managers(manager, manager_dict, manager_list)
    return manager_list 

df['manager_list'] = df.emp_name.apply(lambda x: retrieve_managers(x, manager_dict))

>>> df

Out[71]: 
   emp_id emp_name emp_manager  emp_org_lvl                manager_list
0       1   John S       Bob A            1  [Bob A, Paul P, Charles Y]
1       2    Bob A      Paul P            2         [Paul P, Charles Y]
2       3   Paul P   Charles Y            3                 [Charles Y]
```

Finally, you can in fact self-join a dataframe while subselecting columns.

```
df = df.merge(df[['emp_name', 'emp_manager']], left_on='emp_manager', right_on='emp_name', suffixes=("", f"_joined"), how='left')

>>> df 

Out[82]: 
   emp_id emp_name emp_manager  emp_org_lvl emp_name_joined emp_manager_joined
0       1   John S       Bob A            1           Bob A             Paul P
1       2    Bob A      Paul P            2          Paul P          Charles Y
2       3   Paul P   Charles Y            3             NaN                NaN
```